# Let $H$ be the set of all permutations $\alpha\in S_5$ satisfying $\alpha(2) = 2$. Is $H$ a group?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

Let $H$ be the set of all permutations $\alpha\in S_5$ satisfying $\alpha(2) = 2$. Which of the
properties (closure, associativity, identity, inverses) does $H$ enjoy
under composition of functions?

**Solution:**

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in H$.

**Closure:** For any $\alpha, \beta \in H$, we have $\alpha\beta(2)=\alpha(\beta(2))=\alpha(2)=2 $. Thus composition is closed.

**Associativity:** it's obvious that $(\alpha \beta) \gamma(2)=\alpha (\beta \gamma)(2)$

**Identity:** I guess it is the same as for $ S_5 $. Since it leaves the rest of the elements fixed and especially, at $ 2 $

**Inverses:** Since every permutation in $ H $ leaves $2$ fixed, its inverse also. So for every $ \alpha \in H $ there is an inverse.

I am right?

Comment: The associativity holds in $H$ because it also holds in the bigger group. (The given argument is an argument for something else...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

---

Here's another . . .

It suffices to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_5$, since every subgroup of a group is itself a group.

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Since the identity in $S_5$ fixes $2$ trivially,  we have $H\neq\varnothing$.

Let $\sigma\in H$. Then $\sigma\in S_5$ such that $\sigma(2)=2$; so, in particular, $\sigma\in S_5$. Hence $H\subseteq S_5$.

Let $\sigma,\tau\in H$. Then $\sigma(2)=2$ and $\tau(2)=2$. Since $\tau$ is a bijection on $\{1,\dots, 5\}$ that fixes $2$, so is its inverse $\tau^{-1}\in H$ (because $$\begin{align}
\tau^{-1}(2)&=\tau^{-1}(\tau(2))\\
&=(\tau^{-1}\tau)(2)\\
&={\rm id}_{S_5}(2)\\
&=2).
\end{align}$$ We have

$$\begin{align}
(\sigma\tau^{-1})(2)&=\sigma(\tau^{-1}(2))\\
&=\sigma(2)\\
&=2,
\end{align}$$

but the composition of two bijections is a bijection, so $\sigma\tau^{-1}\in H$.

Hence $H\le S_5$.

Hence $H$ is a group.